# Stripping slashes in each value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server

I have an array of values I am getting from an SQL call but when I try to put it into a table in my web page, I get the error:

```
JSON.parse: bad escaped character at line 1 column 657 of the JSON data
```

I have realised that in the data, one of the rows has the data: INNO BROWN THOMAS TV\'S

This is causing the error because of the escaping character, the large result set is coming back as an array and I need some sort of loop in php to remove these slashes and stop the error. What is the best way to do this? I have looked at the PHP Manual for `addslashes` and `stripslashes` and I have tried looping around an array to remove the slashes but nothing works.

Any help or points in the right direction will be appreciated, thanks.

```
$prodSQL = new prodEnqSQL;
$results = $prodSQL->getProdData($prodName, $prodType, $prodCode);
function stripslashes_array($results){
    global $results;
    if(is_array($results)){
        foreach ($results as $key=>$value){
            $value[$key] = stripslashes_array($value);
        }

    }else{
        return stripslashes($results);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: why it is sql-server?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy because the results i am getting are from sql-server

Comment: Which version of sql server/

Comment: i am using 2012, is there a way  to do this through sql instead of php?

Comment: String_escape function is there in SQL Server 2016 which will provide this data automatically else we might require to use replace

Comment: If you are writing the SQL that pulls out the data, `replace(ColName,'\','')` will remove all the backslashes from that column's data.

Comment: @iamdave that works great for what i wanted thanks, i didnt know you could do that through sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sql server 2016, You can use STRING_ESCAPE of sql server while querying as below:

```
select string_escape(yourcolumn, 'json') from yourtable
```

if < SQL Server 2016

```
select replace(yourcolumn,'\','\\') from yourtable
```

Comment: Thanks, Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work for you

```
foreach ($your_array as $key=>$value) {
    $your_array[$key] = stripslashes($value);
    }
```

or for many levels array use this :

```
function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}

$array = array("f\\'oo", "b\\'ar", array("fo\\'o", "b\\'ar"));
$array = stripslashes_deep($array);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: I am getting `stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`